# Deployment: this.Context.Parameters not available throughout installation process

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-installer

I have the following code but although I can access a property and retrieve a value

```
 this.Context.Parameters["SERVICENAME"]
```

in BeforeInstall, the same property returns "" in OnCommitted.

Where does this data go, how does it gets wiped, where can I find a breakdown of the order of each of these methods and what gets passed where?

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {

        public string ServiceName { get; protected set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="savedState"></param>
        protected override void OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);
            this.ServiceName = this.Context.Parameters["SERVICENAME"].ToString();
            this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = this.ServiceName;
            this.serviceInstaller1.DisplayName = this.ServiceName;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// /
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="savedState"></param>
        protected override void OnCommitted(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.OnCommitted(savedState);
            string targetDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Context.Parameters["AssemblyPath"]); ;
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetDirectory, "Services.Win32.exe.config");
            System.Xml.XmlDocument xDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(path);
            System.Xml.XmlNode node = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/applicationSettings/Services.Win32.Properties.Settings/setting[@name='TaskManagerServiceName']/value");
            node.InnerText = (this.ServiceName); // here this.ServiceName is "" so was this.Context.Parameters[""SERVICENAME"] when i was using that
            xDoc.Save(path);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest, cleanest and most robust solution is to not use an installer class custom action to install a service.  Use Windows Installer's built in mechansim: the [ServiceInstall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) table.

The problem is you are likely using Visual Studio Deployment Projects which don't expose this capability.  No problem.  Use Windows Installer XML to author a Merge Module that encapsulates your XE/Service component.  Then add this merge module to your VDPROJ installer.

See the following articles for ideas on how to wire this up:

[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Certificates](http://blog.iswix.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows_19.html)

[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Windows Services](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows_19.html)

[Redemption of Visual Studio Deployment Projects](http://blog.iswix.com/2011/03/redemption-of-visual-studio-deployment.html)

Answer (score 4):

I bumped into this question when trying to add additional parameter to existing deployment project. Parameter was passed to the installer, but wasn't visible in `Context.Parameters`. It turns out that parameters to be accessible need to be added to "custom action data" of that custom action.

You can achieve that by right clicking **.vdproj** project, and picking `View -> Custom Actions`.
From there you can find primary outputs of your custom action. By right clicking primary output in a desired step (Install, Commit, Rollback or Uninstall) and picking properties you can edit **Custom Action Data** for that step. You can find format of that property [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Hope it will save time someone, as it took me quite some time to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

It can be accessed on Install and Uninstall overrides of Installer class:

Here a full example:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{

    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();              
    }

    public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        UpdateServiceName();
        base.Install(stateSaver);
    }

    public override void Uninstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
    {
        UpdateServiceName();
        base.Uninstall(savedState);
    }
    private void UpdateServiceName()
    {
        var serviceName = Context.Parameters["servicename"];

        //if service name was set has install parameter then override the value set on the designer:
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceName))
        {

            //serviceInstaller1 is the `ServiceInstaller` component drag to install designer.
            this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = serviceName;

            //Since user can change service name and do multiple side installs, by keep the display names similar it can help to keep those side installs packed in Service Management Console.
            this.serviceInstaller1.DisplayName = $"{this.serviceInstaller1.DisplayName} ({serviceName})";
        }
    }
}
```